# PHP and Postgresql, DEFAULT not working

Tags: php, postgresql, default

I'm trying to do an insert where I use the value DEFAULT because I have the table setup with a sequence for ID (INTEGER), so it would auto-increment.

If I execute the query manually, it works perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Name T', 35, 9, 0);
```

However, when I execute it from PHP, it does not work:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (DEFAULT, '$name', $age, $type, 0)";
pg_query($query);
```

I know the problem it's with DEFAULT, because if I replace it with a number, it will insert fine from PHP as well.

Any idea?

Comment: "*it does not work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (DEFAULT, '$name', $age, $type, 0)";
$rc = pg_query($query);

$rc is null after. Satisfied?

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. This definitely works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d0a7a/1  Please show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: > If an error occurs, and FALSE is returned, details of the error can be retrieved using the pg_last_error() function if the connection is valid

Comment: I don't have the CREATE TABLE. Certainly, it probably doesn't matter. The same query works fine when executed from command line in postgresql. If the table was the problem, I assume it wouldn't work from console either.

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro. I was able to find the problem.
ERROR: permission denied for sequence ids.

Comment: Actually, I know nothing about PostgreSQL. Feel free to answer the question yourself and explain how to assign such permissions.

Comment: To update permissions: grant all on table people to "www-user";
This is for granting all permissions, but can grant only certain permissions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't insert any value for that field at all and let the sequence's default value be populated for you. Of course that means you need to specifically name your fields in your insert query.

Comment: That seems very logical and with MySQL that's how it probably works. However, it does not work with Postgresql if using a sequence.

Comment: Excluding the column value on an insert will provide the default value for the column.  If it is serial column with sequence on it, then, the next value will be utilized.

Comment: It's integer type, not serial. Otherwise I wouldn't be using a sequence.

Comment: I'll accept your solution because I can't accept Álvaro's. The problem is I omitted to set permissions for the sequence.

Comment: @xBlue That is really the same thing. A serial type and an integer type hold the same range of integer data (except no negatives in serial). A serial type just automatically generates the sequence for you when creating the table and makes the field `NOT NULL`.  It is in essence a shorthand for declaring an auto-incrementing integer field.